# In Xamarin Forms, it is possible to reload the current page when screen rotates without using ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, screen-rotation

I have an android menu because I needed a searchview inside of a toolbar. When I add `ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation` to my activity and the screen rotates, my menu is recreated (as expected).

But when I travel to another xamarin forms page and rotate the screen, the screen goes back to the very first screen (I am assuming because there is only on activity an the screen rotation cause on create to fire, thus the only activity(the first activity) is reload).

If I remove the setting `ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation`, and add  `OnConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)`, my screen is retained on rotation, but i lose my menu. How do i go about fixing this issue?

Comment: there is something else going on. Those parameters don't cause page change

Comment: can i setup and example and send it to you @YuriS?

Comment: sure, post it somewhere

Comment: @YuriS - checkout these to demos of the problem that i am having. In the project DemoLostMenu, if you rotates the screen, you lose the menu. If you were to go to page two, and rotate the screen you would still be on page two. In the project DemoLostState, if you rotate the screen, you still retain your menu. But if you go to page two, and rotate the screen, you would be imediately transfer to page one.

Comment: https://github.com/Daron-Rice/SideProjects/tree/master/test/testOne

Comment: https://github.com/Daron-Rice/SideProjects/tree/master/test

Comment: whatever advice you have to fix this issue, i would gladly appreciate it.

Comment: what device/simulator you are testing on?

Comment: One advice. If you are using Forms you should create your menus in Forms not in Android native code. Use Toolbar in forms

Comment: I am testing on a Kyocera reach. Android device. I was going to use regular forms toolbar but they have no way to out the searchbar in the toolbar (which is a requirement for my application)

Comment: If forms had a way to put the searchbar in the toolbar, I would be using forms toolbar.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.SearchBar/

Comment: i have seen that...the only problem with it is that it is not in the navigation bar....that is the requirement. "seachbar in navbar"...is there a way for me to use that searchbar in a navbar?

Comment: I have not tried but may be that will work for you? http://blog.xhackers.co/xamarin-forms-contentpage-with-searchbar-in-the-navigation-bar/